# A Set of Linear Equations Equal to Zero

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

If A+B+C+D = 1;

Let A,B,C,D be elements of vector **V**.

Let there be a 4*4 matrix **M** as such :

```
  -5  5  0  0
   4 -8  4  0
   0  5 -7  2
   0  0 10 -10
```

A property exist that **VM** = 0.

- What is V=[?, ? ,? ,?] ?

I have tried to solve this on matlab and failed. I always reach to conclusion that the vector V are all 0,0,0,0.

Also that solves the equation as well, that is not the answer i am looking for since the SUM of V=1.

The answer should be a non zero value.

These are the set of equations:

```
4b-5a =0
5a-8b+5c=0
4b-7c+10d=0
2c-10d=0
```

Comment: I will love to know why i had a thump down and why the other answers do. People should take responsibility of using that power instead of sitting behind their desk and just thumbing down to show power.

Comment: Hurkyl has explained the situation mathematically quite well; if you see my comment on his answer, you can find MATLAB code that will do what you want. I suggest really trying to understand both the math and the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you *sure* that $vM=0$ has infinitely many solutions for $v$?

The question asked is more of a `matlab` question than a math question: you need to find the function that returns the space of all solutions (i.e. the left nullspace of $M$), not just one.

Or, you could ask `matlab` to solve the equation you're *really* trying to solve:

```
  /  |1\
v |M |1| = [0 1]
  |  |1|
  \  |1/
```

Comment: The MATLAB command would simply be `null(A')'`. Or, to ensure all elements sum to $1$, `null(A')'./(sum(null(A')))`

Comment: @Hurkyl Thanks for the help

Comment: @Arkamis I am trying to do this with matlab now. Although i am new to it, i find my self confused on how to calculate this. I already defined a matrix called M and inserted the values. How should i define the vector V in matlab ? and after having the variables what command should i use to get the answer ? that which you provided in your last comment ?

Comment: Then literally change `A` to `M` and copy and paste my code. Please view the documentation for the `null` command. Note that `null(A)` returns the *right* nullspace of `A`. Note that the left nullspace of $A$ is the right nullspace of $A^T$ (this is an important result that should be part of your study). So we use `null(A')` to compute the *right* nullspace of $A^T$, which is equivalent to the left-nullspace of $A$, transposed. Hence, `null(A')'` returns the left-nullspace of the matrix. To ensure that the resulting vector sums to 1, we simply divide by the sum of whatever we get...

Comment: because MATLAB returns the vector whose *sum-of-squares* is 1, instead.

Comment: @Arkamis Thanks, when i do  `Z=null(M')'` I get ` Empty matrix: 0-by-4`  When i do ` Z=null(M')'./(sum(null(M')))` I get, `Error using  ./ 
Matrix dimensions must agree.`

Comment: @Arkamis Sorry if i am doing something so basic yet failing.

Comment: @Undisputed007 Then you have not input the matrix properly. Here: `A = [-5 5 0 0; 4 -8 4 0; 0 5 -7 2; 0 0 10 -10];
null(A')'./(sum(null(A')))`

Comment: @Arkamis Thanks you were right !

Answer (score -2):

Add the first and second equation. This gives $-4b = 0$, $b = 0$, and subsequently using the first equation $a = 0$.

Adding the third and fourth equation gives $c = 0$, $d = 0$.

Therefore $Mv$ does note have non-trivial solutions.